# How I can combine the values of two Set Inside HashMap java

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, collections, hashmap

I have two Set inside a hashmap that I want to combine there values in the other Set:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> entry : myhashmap.entrySet()) {
  // in the first iteration  entry.getValue() give me elementValues1 Set
  // and the second give elementValues2 
}
```

For example, my first HashSet in the first iteration contains those values: `A, B`.

Like :

```
Set<String> elementValues1 = new HashSet<String>();
elementValues1.add("A");
elementValues1.add("B");
```

and my second Set in the second iteration contains: `C, D`.

Like :

```
Set<String> elementValues2 = new HashSet<String>();
elementValues2.add("C");
elementValues2.add("D");
```

I want to create another set inside the loop that combine the values of the two Set : 
Like :

```
Set<String> elementValues3 = new HashSet<String>();
```

`elementValues3` should contain : 
    A-C
    A-D
    B-C
    B-D

Can someone help me fix this problem thank in advance

Comment: Have you tried using [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))?

Comment: addAll will give me a set with values :A,B,C,D

Comment: iterate over both and then add in third hashset.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 5):

In case you really want the String couples with the **-** delimiter, simply loop both the Sets and add the merged values to the 3rd one:

```
Set<String> elementValues3 = new HashSet<String>();
for (String s1: elementValues1) {
    for (String s2: elementValues2) {
        elementValues3.add(s1 + "-" + s2);
    }
}
```

The pritned result will be:

> [A-C, A-D, B-C, B-D]

Answer (score 5):

in Java 8 you can benefit from streams:

```
Set<String> newSet 
       = elementValues1.stream()
       .flatMap(a -> elementValues2.stream()
       .map(b -> a + '-' + b))
       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```